# OHttpClient get request with valid I.CA certificate

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, okhttp

I'm new to setting up certificates, the endpoint requires a valid certificate issued by I.CA. I have a .pfx with the password and can get the data from the endpoint in Postman. However I fail to achieve the same from my local server running on localhost:8080.

I'm using okhttp version 4.7.2

Here is a breakdown of the code I'm using, the loading does not cause any errors and is just for demo code adjusted. I'm having in the keystore 38 providers and only the cert under keystoreSpi that I loaded. Both key and cert are not null and seems to contain the certificate. The endpoint just return a 403 (according to docu means authorization headers ('x-api-key', 'Authorization' or 'x-client-cert') is not valid.) Since I confirmed with Postman that the api key and the token is valid (token flow is working), it can be just the missing cert. But I do not know what else is missing for the request.

```
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("filepath\\cert.pfx"))) {
            keystore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        String alias = "myAlias";
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

        HeldCertificate heldCertificate = new HeldCertificate.Builder()
                .keyPair(new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key))
                .build();

        HandshakeCertificates handshakeCerts = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
                .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
                .heldCertificate(heldCertificate)
                .build();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().sslSocketFactory(handshakeCerts.sslSocketFactory(), handshakeCerts.trustManager())
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://apiendpoint/name")
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("x-api-key", "Bearer apiKey")
                .addHeader("x-correlation-id", "corId")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken())
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Edit

I'm getting for response.handshake().peerPrincipal().getName() as CN the name of the endpoint I have to integrate. But response.handshake().localPrincipal().getName() is null. How do is set the localPrincipal to include the certificate that I loaded.

Here is the successful postman call.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the client authentication is working you should look at the localPrincipal in the handshake.

```
    Call call = client.newCall(new Request.Builder().url(server.url("/")).build());
    Response response = call.execute();
    assertThat(response.handshake().peerPrincipal()).isEqualTo(
        new X500Principal("CN=Local Host"));
    assertThat(response.handshake().localPrincipal()).isEqualTo(
        new X500Principal("CN=Jethro Willis"));
    assertThat(response.body().string()).isEqualTo("abc");
```

It might be that your client certificate is not being accepted, and falling back allowing the connection but failing the request.

In your request, this header looks troubling, are you sure you provide this as is, which Authorization includes the actual access token?

```
.addHeader("x-api-key", "Bearer apiKey")
```

See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

The actual handshake including client happens at a layer below OkHttp, so if it's a JDK app then you might need to enable debug flags for that.  Wireshark or similar can also help you debug if you are really motivated.

Comment: I updated the question with more information. localPrincipal is null, how do I set it correctly with my cert?

Comment: > The actual handshake including client happens at a layer below OkHttp, so if it's a JDK app then you might need to enable debug flags for that. Wireshark or similar can also help you debug if you are really motivated.